# JsonConvert.SerializeObject on an exception loses the message

Tags: c#, json.net

Never seen this before, basically my MSMQ call is throwing an access denied, which in visual studio appears as this (`exception.ToString()`)

> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Access to
>   Message Queuing system is denied.\r\n   at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()\r\n
>   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS
>   properties, IntPtr transaction)\r\n   at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj,
>   MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction,
>   MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)\r\n   at
>   redacted.d__2.MoveNext() in c:\path\file.cs:line 24

Now this gets logged in a call to a class library that contains my logging code.

My code does this:

```
var logMessage = new LogEntry(applicationName, exception, message, level);
```

`LogEntry` is just a plain old class that puts those things into properties, doesn't do anything else.

`var logEntryAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage);`

This line should serialize it to JSON. When it does however, the exception property changes to this:

> "Exception":{"NativeErrorCode":-1072824283,"ClassName":"System.Messaging.MessageQueueException","Message":"External
>   component has thrown an
>   exception.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"
>   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()\r\n
>   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS
>   properties, IntPtr transaction)\r\n   at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj,
>   MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction,
>   MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)\r\n   at
>   redacted.d__2.MoveNext() in c:\path\file.cs:line
>   24","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nget_WriteHandle\nSystem.Messaging,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\nSystem.Messaging.MessageQueue+MQCacheableInfo\nSystem.Messaging.Interop.MessageQueueHandle
>   get_WriteHandle()","HResult":-2147467259,"Source":"System.Messaging","WatsonBuckets":null}

The intellisense, hovering over the logMessage object on the serialization line, is showing the first exception data. But when serialized, it's completely changing it. As a result the reason for the error is not logged so I was scratching my head for a while trying to debug it.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? Do I have to force the exception to be stored as a string?

Comment: `ToString()` produces a formatted string, and may or may not export all public properties.  `JsonConvert` on the other serializes all public properties as JSON, it doesn't change anything. There's no reason to expect them to be the same.

Comment: BTW the way the text is formatted right now, it's hard to see what the difference is. At least post the JSON string as a formatted JSON string, not a quote

Comment: You'd assume that the exception message would be visible though, no?

Comment: Nothing is visible right now, it's just unformatted strings. The `Message` property *is* visible `"Message":"External component has thrown an exception."`. Try serializing the exception object itself, not the `LogEntry` object

Comment: In any case, `ToString()` produces a *formatted string*. It doesn't just print the properties. It uses .NET's resource files to produce the texts, allowing it to localize the output. It's quite likely that `MessageQueueException.ToString()` looks up the error code to produce a meaningful message

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your response. exception.Message is `"Access to Message Queuing system is denied."` before it's serialized, but it serializes to `External component has thrown an exception`. None of this is explained by `ToString()`

Comment: It's actually the overriden [Message](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/MessageQueueException.cs,65) that produces a different string based on the `nativeerrorcode` field.

Comment: Then why does `exception.Message` give me the error message I want, but when the serializer is ran, it produces something different?

Comment: The source code links provided by Orace and me show that it *is* the difference in `ToString()` and `Message` that causes this. `Exception` already has support for serialization though. You can extract all the internal data needed with `GetObjectData` and rehydrate an identical exception on the other side with the `Exception(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)` constructor

Comment: It does not answer the question of why there is a difference, if there's a custom implementation that's fine, but then *both* `ToString()` and the serialization should produce the same custom result. Catching the exception as an `ExternalException` instead of `Exception` and calling `ToString()` gives identical results. So there must be something else.

Comment: Because `Message` is a readonly property? In that case the serializer may be trying to read from the backing field, which contains the value stored by `ExternalException`. It doesn't know this is actually a *calculated* exception. As for producing identical results, on the contrary, that `Message`implementation load a message from resources *every* time it's called. It even expects to find *no* message, hence the `catch`

Comment: Wouldn't the backing field be private? Why would doing `.Message` in my code be different from Json serializer calling `.Message`? You said yourself that JSON serializes public properties, and that it doesn't change anything. I'm afraid nothing you've said really seems to make any sense at all.

Comment: JSON.NET respects the `ISerializable` interface and only serializes the properties it provides. This behavior can be disabled

Comment: As for how private fields, get serialized, through reflection. Especially for `get` only properties that are set by the constructor, both Json.NET and Dapper have to do some gymnastics to find and *set* the auto-generated backing field. Otherwise it would be impossible to deserialize those properties

Answer (score 2):

The `Exception` class implements ISerializable. Json.NET [recognizes this and only serializes the properties specified by the class itself](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable). As the docs explain :

> **ISerializable**
>
> Types that implement ISerializable and are marked with SerializableAttribute are serialized as JSON objects. When serializing, only the values returned from ISerializable.GetObjectData are used; members on the type are ignored. When deserializing, the constructor with a SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is called, passing the JSON object's values.
>
> In situations where this behavior is not wanted, the JsonObjectAttribute can be placed on a .NET type that implements ISerializable to force it to be serialized as a normal JSON object.

The [MessageQueueException.Message](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/MessageQueueException.cs,65) property is computed at runtime and loads a string from .NET runtime's resources. [It's not saved by GetObjectData](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/MessageQueueException.cs,111) because the actual text is neither needed nor wanted - when deserialized on another system, `Message` will return the localized string available for that system.

`External component has thrown an exception` comes from the parent [ExternalException](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/externalexception.cs,748093508adc3060) class, which stores a string in `Message` but doesn't override `GetObjectData`.

This isn't a problem for serialization and deserialization, as the data is sufficient to rehydrate the correct object. It's a problem with JSON though, which doesn't contain type information.

This behavior can be *disabled*. One way to do this is to add attributes to the class, which isn't possible with BCL classes. Another possibility is to use a [Contract Resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) that ignores ISerializable. The DefaultContractResolver has properties like [IgnoreSerializableInterface](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm) for this :

```
string json =
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        exception,
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
             ContractResolver = new DefaultContractRresolver {
                   IgnoreSerializableInterface=true
        }}
    );
```